# How do I insert new text (with a line break) to a cell without replacing existing cell value using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help inserting new text into a cell with a line break using Google Apps Script.

I created a form for my Marketing Calendar so all inputs will filter into respective tabs (Months) and into respective cells (Days). Thing is, I don't know how to add cell value/text that doesn't delete the previous data present in the cell.

What would be a proper code to add a line break + new text to a cell without removing existing data on it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const range = sheet.getRange('A1');
let value = range.getValue();
value += '\nNew Text';
range.setValue(value);
```